# How to simulate a composite video input signal in ltspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, video

I want to simulate this video driver circuit (i think it's called that) in ltspice

[image: video driver circuit to provide x, y, z inputs to a CRT driver circuit]

I found this design from this very nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqSiMKwfZsY by the videolabguy.

To simulate the same circuit in ltSpice,  I'll need to have a sample analog video input file. I cannot find this anywhere. Earlier, I had simulated an audio amplifier in ltspice - for that, I provided the input as a .wav file (which is accepted by ltspice). I'm not sure how to do this for analog video input.

I have found a way to convert the usual video format to NTSC standard, which i believe is the standard for the analog video input used in this project. But how to add this video input in ltspice is beyond me. Is there any way to do that in ltspice, or is there any other simulation software I have to use to simulate video input?

Comment: There is something called a "PWL File" choice that you can make for a voltage source in LTspice. I believe that's how you'd do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.